# Define a custom tag that uses Javascript, sending some parameters to it

Tags: javascript, java, thymeleaf

I am a former user of `JSF 2` I enjoyed a lot for its composites that allowed me to avoid most of the time all `javascript` in my html pages. But the era of `JSF 2` has ended...

I am now using `Spring Boot 2` and `Thymeleaf`, and `Thymeleaf` I am using it for the first time.

I have this simple sample of `Openlayers` that shows a map (provided some additionals `<script src=...>` not shown here to declare `Openlayers` and, of course, few others html tags ; It cames directly from http://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html) :

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
      zoom: 4
    })
  });
</script>
```

I would like to find a way my html page have a custom tag such as :

```
<myMaps:display target="map" longitude=37.41 latitude=8.82 zoom=4 />
```

and that would generate at least the `<script>` part of the sample, and at best gather also the `<div>` tag above it.

Can I do this using `Thymeleaf` ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of Thymeleaf supporting custom tags but you can use a [parameterised fragment](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#parameterizable-fragment-signatures) with [JavaScript inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining), eg

```html
<th:block th:fragment="myMaps(target, longitude, latitude, zoom)">
    <div th:id="${target}" class="map"></div>

    <script th:inline="javascript">
        var map = new ol.Map({
            target: [[${target}]],
            layers: [
              new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
              })
            ],
            view: new ol.View({
              center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([
                  [[${longitude}]], 
                  [[${latitude}]]
              ]),
              zoom: [[${zoom}]]
            })
          });
      </script>
</th:block>
```

and include it via

```html
<div th:replace="::myMaps ('map', 37.41, 8.82, 4)"></div>
```

or

```html
<div th:replace="::myMaps (target='map',longitude=37.41,latitude=8.82,zoom=4)"></div>
```